# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy SignUp only with loyaltynumber and email pre-filled

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm creating a custom Sign up only policy that should receive two attributes in the url:

- email adress (optional)
- loyaltynumber (required)

If I have the email address in the url I want it to be pre-filled in the box (and read-only, but I could fix that with html/css?) and the loyalty number.

I've allready created the custom policy but I cannot get the email (=username) pre-filled.

I've created a UserJourney:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUp">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections.signup">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
 
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
```

And a Signup policy:

```
<BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>tenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Add the login hint value to the sign-in names claim type -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUp" />
    
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: What is the URL you are constructing, speficailly the query params sent to B2C? To prepopulate the email, there is an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin), and to capture any query param in the URL, you can use [claims resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview)

Comment: I want to send the parameters 'email' and 'loyaltynr'.The example you gave about pre-populating the email is for the signin policy. I want to do it in the signup policy.